# How do I assign async storage value directly to state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, promise, async-await

I need something like below
but I cant get the value

```
state = {
  phone: async () => await AsyncStorage.getItem('phone')
}

constructor(props){
  super(props)
  alert(this.state.phone);
}
```

but this does not work.

I khow if call it inside componentDidMount and then pass the value to the state, it works
But I need something like above.

Comment: `constructor` function of a class can never be asynchronous. What you're asking for in your hypothetical code isn't possible.

Comment: "async" and "directly" don't go together. It's like wanting to immediately drink the beer that you ask your mate to go fetch from the fridge.

Comment: I just need to fetch phone number from asyncstorage befor constructor gets run or at least inside constuctor. so what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { AsyncStorage } from 'AsyncStorage';

class App extends Component {

  state = {};

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.getItem().then((phone)=>{
        this.setState({
          phone
        });
      })
  }

  async getItem(){
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem('phone');
  }

  async setItem(){
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('phone','919303580');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Phone here:</p>
        {this.state.phone && <p>{this.state.phone}</p>}
        <button onClick={this.setItem.bind(this)}>Click me</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you this works, but there will not be problem if we update the state inside constructor?

Comment: I would then suggest that you use `componentDidMount()` for that.